# What is Magento payment default behavior with the payment gateway?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm using one of the payment gateways

if the customer select to pay online then click on place order.
Then he will redirect to the payment page and at the same time, the order will create if the payment is successful the order status will be complete if not then the order status will be processing. if the customer closes the payment page before doing payment the order status will be canceled.

Is this is a default Magento behavior with payment gateways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is the magento default payment behavior.

1. When `Place Order` button click on Magento, it create order into system and set status `pending` and redirect customer to payment gateway for the payment.
2. Now, If customer make the payment on gateway, then gateway redirect to website and Magento change the order status `processing`.
3. Instead of payment, customer cancel the payment, then gateway redirect them to site and make the order status to `cancel`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Is there any way to edit the order? because some orders need to change after being created 1- products are out of stock or 2- the customer changes his mind and he wants to change product

Comment: Yes, you need to do the customization into particular payment gateway extension according to your requirement.

Comment: If my answer help you please upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other in community.